# Problem with repeating(AlarmManager)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm building an app that has to show a notifcation after some period, for that i used AlarmManager.
To have a notification every 15 minutes we have to do this:

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 900000, pi);
```

For a day we have `86400000` as value. My idea is to make also a notification every week( multiply 86400000 with 7) and every month(multiply 86400000 with 28). The problem is in month constant, i have:

```
The literal 2419200000 of type int is out of range
```

It's not possible to make a long period notifications with AlarmManager? Is there a solution ?
Thank you.
EDIT:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(choix_notif) == 0)
            {
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 86400000, pi);
            Log.d("DAY_REPEATING","OK");
            }
            else if (Integer.valueOf(choix_notif) == 1) {
                mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 604800000, pi);
                Log.d("WEEK_REPEATING","OK");
            }
            else if (Integer.valueOf(choix_notif) == 2) {
                mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 2419200000L, pi);
                Log.d("MONTH_REPEATING","OK");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible (as [`setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) receives long as parameter), but instead of `2419200000` , you should write `2419200000L` since 2419200000 is too big for int, and any integer constant is treated as `int`, so you need to add the `L` to indicate this number is long.

Comment: Aha, good trick ;). Thank you very much. And my idea of multiplication is it good and functionnal ? In the official documentary there is just a day as max value.

Comment: @androniennn - Actually, even multiplication will not help, since it will overflow, you have to use the `L` in multiplication too, to indicate that you multiply long numbers and not `int`s

Comment: So i have to add the `L` in the other values of day and week `86400000` and `604800000` ? I'm not having any error :\(please see my edited post)

Comment: if the multiplication will result is bigger than `int` maximum then yes. otherwise - not.

Comment: Clear ;). So the L will be just in the recent one(bigger than int). Thnak you very much.